# Create a patch showing less deleted lines

Tags: linux, git, diff, patch

I need to create a patch between different versions of software in two directories and that patch will be delivered to my client. They need to be able to apply that patch to the older version to update it to the newer version. Due to security requirements (look for malicious code, etc.), I must read every single line of this patch with my own eyeballs. I'd like to not have to read all of the deleted code, because if there are 150k deleted lines and 100k added lines, I have to read through 250k lines, when really only 100k of them are worth reading.

Currently I will create the patch using:

```
diff -N -r --unified=1 old new > patch.diff
```

The patch is then applied using:

```
cp -r old new
cd new
patch -N -p1 < ../patch.diff
```

As an example, I have this directory structure:

```
[user@hostname test]$ tree -af
.
├── ./new
│   ├── ./new/a.txt
│   ├── ./new/b.txt
│   └── ./new/c.txt
└── ./old
    ├── ./old/a.txt
    └── ./old/c.txt
```

In the new version, a new file b.txt was added, a.txt was modified, and c.txt had all lines removed but still exists. Running my current patch creation would result in this diff:

```
[user@hostname test]$ diff -N -r --unified=1 old new
diff -N -r '--unified=1' old/a.txt new/a.txt
--- old/a.txt   2019-07-01 18:09:59.586410797 -0400
+++ new/a.txt   2019-07-01 18:17:19.680446218 -0400
@@ -3,2 +3,3 @@
 a
+h
 a
@@ -8,2 +9,3 @@
 a
+awdwd
 a
@@ -11,23 +13,5 @@
 a
-a
-a
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
-b
 b
+foo
+bar
 b
@@ -39,2 +23,9 @@
 c
+d
+d
+d
+d
+d
+d
+d

diff -N -r '--unified=1' old/b.txt new/b.txt
--- old/b.txt   1969-12-31 19:00:00.000000000 -0500
+++ new/b.txt   2019-07-01 18:10:52.943204070 -0400
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+this is an entirely new file
diff -N -r '--unified=1' old/c.txt new/c.txt
--- old/c.txt   2019-07-01 18:16:11.820985994 -0400
+++ new/c.txt   2019-07-01 18:14:59.775620402 -0400
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-this is a file that will be empty in the new version
```

Ideally, I wouldn't have to read all of the removed lines of "b" in a.txt. The patch file could just indicate the line numbers to remove without their content, or maybe fold whole deleted sections larger than N - doesn't matter to me as long as the patch can still be applied safely.

Comment: I always liken `diff -uNb ...` to `ignore changes in the amount of white space` or try `diff -uNBw ...` to `ignore all white space` and `ignore changes where lines are all blank`

Comment: Or just shorten your read by computationally removing the lines containing only `'b'` or `"-b"` from your review with `grep -v '[-]*b$' a.txt` (you will have confirmed the content of every line)

Answer (score 1):

git does not support generating a patch in the form you're wanting, and would not want to apply such a patch if it were provided, because it would be unable to verify if the patch were applying as intended.  I realize this measure of safety might not apply to your use case, but it does apply to the use case git patches are intended to serve.

So, for example, if you have a file

```
a
b
c
```

and you edit it to

```
a
c
```

you might want a patch that just says "delete line 2"; but when you apply the patch to a target copy, git is worried that the copy might have been modified - since git's whole purpose is distributed development.  And if the target were edited so that line 2 is now anything but

```
b
```

then there is technically a conflict.

(There is a `-D` option to `git format-patch` which is related to what you want, but it only omits the pre-images of *entire files* that are deleted.)

So you'd need some other tool.  I don't know a good one for this purpose.  You could write some custom scripts, but the complexity and risk is higher than it might initially seem.